Short story probably in Omni magazine in the 1980s set in a cyberpunk bar… but it's 1899 or so
I read this story about 40 years ago.
It's set in a bar with a flickering hologram, neon, etc.  Other cyberpunk tropes might be present.  One person tells another person an outrageous story – perhaps about time travel?  The second person says "Buddy, no one's going to believe a crazy story like that in 1899".
Anyone?

This is Joe Haldeman's "No Future In It", published in the April 1979 edition of Omni, and in the first "The Best of Omni Science Fiction" collection. It can be read here on the Internet Archive
It's set in a "sleazy bar in downtown Tampa", and is framed as a conversation between two patrons, one of whom claims to be a time traveler from 1983.
The last paragraph:

Space settlements. Time travel. Nobody would swallow that line of bull in 1924.


That's it! Thanks!
